# Design pattern: Extracting common functionality

Tags: design-patterns

I've the following code. I've 2 different jobs which calls the same below mentioned processor class. Both the job do almost the same thing but differ only in the last step. Currently, i am handling it on the basis of the boolean variable 'createReport'. I wanted to extract the 90% common functionality out into a single class.

I thought about template pattern. But how do i inject the dependency of repositoryA in the abstract class?

```vb
Imports log4net
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Interface IProcessor
    Sub Process(path As String, includeCache As Boolean, createReport As Boolean)
End Interface

Public Class Processor
    Implements IProcessor

    Private ReadOnly _repositoryA As IRepositoryA
    Private ReadOnly _repositoryB As IRepositoryB
    Private ReadOnly _logger As ILog

    Public Sub New(repositoryA As IRepositoryA, repositoryB As IRepositoryB, logger As ILog)
        If repositoryA Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("repositoryA")
        End If

        If repositoryB Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("repositoryB")
        End If

        If logger Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("logger")
        End If

        _repositoryA = repositoryA
        _repositoryB = repositoryB
        _logger = logger
    End Sub

    Public Sub Process(folderPaths As String, includeCache As Boolean, createReport As Boolean) Implements IProcessor.Process
        _logger.Info("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(folderPaths) Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("folderPaths")
        End If

        Dim paths() As String = folderPaths.Split(New Char() {";"c})
        For Each path As String In paths
            Dim cList As List(Of Container) = _repositoryA.GetContainers(path, includeCache)
            For Each container As Container In cList
                If Not container.IsDeleted Then
                    Dim assetList As List(Of Asset) = _repositoryA.GetAssets(container.ContainerID)
                    If Not assetList Is Nothing Then
                        For Each asset As Asset In assetList
                            ProcessAsset(asset, createReport)
                        Next
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next

        _logger.Info("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
    End Sub

    Private Sub ProcessAsset(asset As Asset, createReport As Boolean)
        'Again some common business logic

        'at last depending on value of createReport
        If createReport Then
            CreateReport(asset)
        Else
            SyncAsset(asset, ...other arguments)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub SyncAsset(asset As asset, ..other arguments)
        'business logic. Dependency on _repositoryB here
    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateReport(asset As asset)
        'business logic
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Regards,
Suyog

Comment: Please use syntax highlight

Comment: I don't see the problem. Template method sounds like a reasonable approach. What is stopping you from defining the repository variables in the abstract class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would divide your `Process` methods in different classes that express the flow you want your code to follow. Then pass those classes behind an abstraction to the main algorithm, which lets you swap out parts of behavior on the fly.

In this case, you want to list assets, and process each asset. The process does N operations and finalize the asset (ie either sync it of create a report). Let's break it down into subcomponents/interfaces that we could use:

- IAssetListCreator {IEnumerable CreateAssetList();}
- IAssetProcessor { void Process(Asset a, IAssetFinalizer af);}
- IAssetFinalizer { void Finalize(Asset a);}

Now you can compose the different bricks in order to replicate the algorithm you had before:

```
Public Interface IProcessor
    Sub Process(creator as IAssetListCreator, processor as IAssetProcessor, finalizer as IAssetFinalizer)
End Interface

' inside the process class
Public Sub Process(creator as IAssetListCreator, processor as IAssetProcessor, finalizer as IAssetFinalizer) Implements IProcessor.Process
     _logger.Info("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")

  For Each asset As Asset In creator.CreateAssetList()
      processor.Process(asset, finalizer)
    Next

    _logger.Info("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
End Sub

' inside the IAssetProcessor
Private Sub ProcessAsset(asset As Asset, finalizer as IAssetFinalizer)
    'Again some common business logic
    finalizer.Finalize(asset)
End Sub
```

Now each component can be constructed using only the elements it needs: if repositoryA is needed only in the sync behavior, create a class inheriting from `IAssetFinalizer` that uses the repositoryA in the constructor. In the same spirit, only the `IAssetListCreator` instance needs to know about a path that the assets are in, or whether the cache should be involved, etc...

I went full steam ahead in breaking down the original code; you could still use the listing code in the Process function but you really benefit from limiting parameters to the components that need them: